# UISegmentedControl not following height constraint exactly

Tags: ios, constraints, height, uisegmentedcontrol

It seem the UISegmentedControl adds some extra hight. I have created a UIView (green) and a UISegmentedControl where I set the height constraint to 56 for both. They should show the same height but it seems the hight is slightly different.
[Result in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0q7f.png)

Here are the constraints from IB.
[constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB5ov.png)

Comment: I think you are talking about width not height.

Comment: no, I mean height and I got an answer already

Answer (score 0):

`UISegmentedControl` has a few quirks with its sizing.

Prior to iOS 13, its Height is actually 2-pts greater than what you see in Storyboard / IB. Starting with iOS 13, it is 1-pt greater.

I don't know *why*, but it is related to the borders (pre-13) and the "padding" (13).

If you want another UI element to match exactly, you'll need to take that into account.